# I want to create 2 docker networks with same IP range

Tags: docker, networking, docker-network

I want to create two docker networks with same ip range and should statically assign the IP address

```
docker network create --driver=bridge --subnet=192.168.0.0/16 'network_one'
docker network create --driver=bridge --subnet=192.168.0.0/16 'network_two'
```

Comment: Can you comment more on _why_ you want to do this?

Comment: i need a few containers with same ip address.

Comment: If you can update to your question to explain *why* you need to do this, we might be able to help you find an alternative solution.

Comment: Right, but _why_ ?

Answer (score 3):

Docker won't let you do that.  Having two identical networks attached to two different interfaces on your host would greatly complicate routing. Docker is not designed to manage the host-level routes that would be necessary for this configuration to work correctly.

Comment: is there any other way for having two containers with same ip address?

Comment: You can start two containers on the same network in `--privileged` mode, and then manually set the ip address.